# Java SSL socket message transfer, Object or byte[]?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client/server model. They communicate with each other with specific message formats. Each message has several fields, like, request_type(4 bytes), request_parameters(String[]), flag(1 byte). Which is the better way to reassemble the message sent to other side? bytes[] array or an Object which wraps all fields?

Comment: Do you have Java at both sides? If so, why not using simple serialization?

Comment: Yes. If object is chosen, what if I want to send a list of strings with unknown size?

Comment: I usually prefer using some class that implements Serializable. That's no problem sending lists over the wire, because all default implementations of java.util.List implement Serializable.

Comment: Is that list ArrayList?

Comment: Yep. Not only java.util.ArrayList but also java.util.LinkedList, java.util.Vector...

Comment: Isn't LinkedList used by pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Sending a object would be better so that you can access fields easily and don't have to analyze fields in bytes[] array.